# Preserving Sauces With Meat

Tags: sauce

I'm making a hot dog sauce that contains tomatoes, bacon & soy sauce. I've tried to preserve it with vinegar, but lost the taste of the product. What can I use to preserve the sauce in a glass container and how long could I store it in a refrigerator?

Answer (score 3):

When preserving food, safety is of top importance, so I would not recommend experimenting haphazardly with sealed jars and preservatives. Generally, cooked leftovers can be kept in the fridge for [3 to 4 days](https://www.mayoclinic.org/food-safety/expert-answers/faq-20058500) with no special treatment. If you need to keep your sauce for longer than that, we need to do something else.

**Pressure canning** cooked meat is feasible; however, it uses specialized equipment. It also requires some exactitude to do safely. Unless you are interested in diving into the rabbit hole of canning, I do not think this technique would be convenient.

**Using acid** to preserve your sauce is a bad idea. Although vinegar or another acid can prevent microbial growth (for example, in a jar of pickles) any significant quantity will make your sauce too sour as you already observed.

**Freezing** is probably your best bet, both from a food safety and a convenience perspective. Put the sauce in a plastic container, or even better a [plastic bag](https://www.seriouseats.com/2016/09/the-best-fastest-way-to-freeze-defrost-food.html). It can be safely frozen for weeks or months. When ready to use, there are [multiple ways](https://www.fsis.usda.gov/wps/portal/fsis/topics/food-safety-education/get-answers/food-safety-fact-sheets/safe-food-handling/the-big-thaw-safe-defrosting-methods-for-consumers/CT_Index) to safely defrost the sauce. But the easiest is just to reheat from frozen, either on the stove or in the microwave.

Comment: Given that the meat involved is bacon, does the possibility of it being shelf-stable (some bacon is) change this answer in any way?

Comment: @Onyz even without the meat altogether I would still recommend freezing. In particular, shelf-stable bacon is protected by its high level of salt and low level of moisture. But the final sauce is going to be less salty and have higher water content.